# Undefined function 'taylorexp' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, recursion

I have a error

This is my code en MATLAB

exponential recursive

```
     function sumac=taylorexp(x,n)



        if n==0     sumac=1; 

        else   sumac=((x^(n)/factorial(n)))+taylorexp(x^(n-1),n-1));  

        end  

        end
```

Comment: Have you saved this code in a file called `taylorexp.m` ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code both contains a syntax error (you are closing a parenthesis you never opened) and I believe it does not what you want. I suppose you wanted to compute the Taylor's expansion of exp(t) in the point x up to the n-th order. The following code does so:

```
function sumac = taylorexp(x,n)
     if n == 0
         sumac = 1;
     else
         sumac = x^n/factorial(n) + taylorexp(x,n-1);
     end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

At first I say welcome to you.

Our friend @Noah Levenstein answer is true but I think some completion is needed that I couldn't add them as an edit to his answer.

> 1. Parenthesis are mismatch. Use @Noah's answer.
> 2. Save your function in a `taylorexp.m` and just call it from another script.
> 3. Don't use double (Non Integer) numbers. `factorial` just work with `n=0,1,2,...` not with something like `2.2` or something like `6.81`.
> 4. Using non Integer numbers for `n` has another problem too: Your recursive function never can satisfy end condition and falls in infinite loop

I think your main problem is #3 or #4 but if not, feel free to comment.